# Spring Data Neo4j 4.0: Duplicate nodes created, should create relationship instead

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

**Summary:** 
With `SDN4`, I'm persisting 10 objects of which half have the same content only the id's to which they are linked differ. The linking ID's are set as `@Transient`. Still, two objects are created with the same content instead of one with two links to it. How can I avoid this behavior?

**Detail:**
We have two domain objects defined and the information sources via CSV, they look as follows:

Domain object A CSV:

```
key,name
1,test1
3,test3
```

POJO A:

```
@Transient
private int key;    
private String name;

@Relationship(type = "HAS_CERTIFICATION", direction = "OUTGOING")
private Set<B> bObject = new HashSet<>();

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Relationship(type = "HAS_CERTIFICATION", direction = "OUTGOING")
public void hasCertification(B b) {
    bObject.add(b);
    b.getA().add(this);
}
```

Domain object B:

```
foreignKey,name,value
1,ISO9001,TRUE
1,ISO14001,TRUE
3,ISO9001,TRUE
3,ISO14001,TRUE
```

POJO B:

```
@Transient
private int foreignKey;
private String name;
private String value;

@Relationship(type = "HAS_CERTIFICATION", direction = "INCOMING")
private Set<A> a = new HashSet<>();

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Relationship(type = "HAS_CERTIFICATION", direction = "INCOMING")
public Set<A> getA() {
    return a;
}
```

These CSV files are parsed and loaded into SDN4 within their respective POJO's (A and B).

Now we loop over these objects and add the relationships:

```
private void aHasCertification(
        Optional<List<B>> b,
        Optional<List<A>> a) {
    for (A aObj : a()) {
        for (B bObj : b()) {
            if(bObj.getForeignKey() == aObj.getKey()) {
                aObj.hasCertification(bObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the root repository, repositoryA, is used to save the loaded objects. `repositoryA.save(domainObjectA);`

Now when I query the database; `match n return n;`

for each of the A objects there will be two `ISO9001` and two `ISO14001` objects. Instead of what I would expect, one of each with two links to `A:1` and `A:3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, instead of

[image]

you're expecting

[image]?

The OGM has no way of knowing that two instances of B with the same "name" are the same node. What you will need to do is load the B node by property and if it exists, use it to relate to A, otherwise create it.
I suspect you'll need to process the CSV data a bit further instead of modelling your objects with almost a 1:1 mapping to a CSV row.

Comment: Okay that answered my questions, it won't recognize it is a duplicate just by the contents of the node. I'll have to do some CSV processing before hand. Thanks